# C read function Undefined error: 0

Tags: c

When I am calling the c read function the perror function tells me that it is an Undefined error: 0.

This is the snippet of the code that it is exiting due to error:

```
  if( read(fd,&head_data->npts,sizeof(int)) <= 0 )
  {  
        perror("File read error in reading data\n");
        exit(1);
  }
```

head_data is a struct and npts is an int member of that struct.

I've looked through the opengroup and the linux man pages but could not find any information on the undefined error. I dont know if it makes any difference but I am compiling and running on Mac OS 10.9.5.

Comment: Probably because `read` returned `0`, which is not considered an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`read(2)` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/read.2.html):

> If successful, the number of bytes actually read is returned.  Upon reading end-of-file, zero is returned.  Otherwise, a -1 is returned and the global variable errno is set to indicate the error.

So you just read 0 bytes - meaning end of file.

Answer (score 1):

So the conditional should simply be updated:

```
  if( read(fd,&head_data->npts,sizeof(int)) < 0 )
  {  
        perror("File read error in reading data\n");
        exit(1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no error, which is why `perror` reports "undefined error". Don't attempt to call `perror` if there's no error. You should only call `perror` is `errno` is not zero. You called `perror` with `errno` being zero. The rest follows.

Function `read` indicates an error condition (which sets `errno`) by returning a *negative* value. Returning zero does not indicate an error condition.

Comment: "You should only call perror is errno is not zero" -- That's the wrong criterion, and in fact good C code generally does not check errno == 0 before calling perror. In many cases errno can be non-zero even when there is no error. Rather, perror should only be called if an error occurred ... in this case, that is indicated by read returning -1.